# How many function templates can be applied to single image service in ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, dem, mosaic, image-service

I am trying to minimize space used on our server by producing a single image service for each county in Maryland.  However, I need to display 6 different derivatives for each county: DEM in feet, meters, stretched, aspect, slope and hillshade.  Does anyone know how many function chain templates I can apply to a single image service? Or will I have to create a image service for each derivative?  The latter seems to defeat the purpose of being able to run on-the-fly processing to a mosaic dataset...

Right now I have each derivative as its own image service... Being that I am not even through half of the counties processing and I am out of memory, I need to find an alternative.